# Подтормаживает, команда nohup

Tags: linux, ssh

Скажите, пожалуйста, не создают ли данные скрипты нагрузку? Например какой-нибудь поток висячих запросов (например как setInterval в JS) или что-то подобное? Потому что я заметил, иногда подтормаживает всё, а в чём причина, понять не могу.

```
nohup /var/www/checker.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

в checker.sh находится, PHP-скрипт самый простой, там один curl запрос:

```
while true; do 
php -f /home/admin/web/domain.ru/public_html/admin/modules/accounts/checker/index.php
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь не nohup виноват, а бесконечный цикл. А если у Вас не выделенный сервер с кучей ядер, а обычный дешевый хостинг, где обычно одно-два ядра, то все занято скриптом. Маловероятно, что Вам нужно так постоянно вызывать этот скрипт. Добавьте `sleep 1` для задержки в одну секунду и посмотрите на результат. Скорее всего серверу полегчает.

Если же нет, запускайте `top` и смотрите, что именно тратит ресурсы.

Comment: скорее всего Вы правы, да. А как вообще правильно запускать скрипт на сервере каждую секунду? Может есть способы проще, чем этот бесконечный цикл?

Comment: для начала нужно подумать, а нужно ли скрипт запускать каждую секунду. В большинстве случаев нет. Даже минута может оказаться достаточной. Иногда я встречался с 30 секундной потребностью, но это делалось через тот же sleep, только предварительно проверялось, сколько времени прошло - ведь исходный скрипт мог выполнятся и секунду, и минуту.

Comment: нужен. Там чекер аккаунтов, на которых нужно отлавливать информацию определённую, а она может появиться в любой момент и исчезнуть спустя несколько секунд.

Comment: если нужно отлавливать изменения, то обычно нужно искать возможность нотификаций